# How we can manage segment control in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, containers, uisegmentedcontrol

How we can manage segment control in storyboard, I created one view Controller on add button click it will jump to another view Controller where i have get the segment control on view and drop the contriner view on it and the generated continer view controller is coneected with three view controller using segue. how can i load view controller into container on selected index.

```
                                           VC
                                            |
                                            |
             SegmentedControl VC Having Segment Control And Container
                                            |
                                            |
                                     Container View Controller
                                            |
                                            |
                                         ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

|                                      |                       |     |                                      |                        |
View Controller1             View Controller2           View Controller3

Comment: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/create-segmented-control-ios7

Answer (score 0):

In `UIViewController` where you have added `segmentedControl`.

1 : Create method as IBAction and connect it with **segmentedControl** as **value changed**

```
 -(IBAction)segmentedControlDidChange:(id)sender {
            UISegmentedControl *segment = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
           NSInteger iIndex = [segment selectedSegmentIndex];
        }
```

2 : Check the index if or switch and call the performSegue method

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"firstIdentifierOfViewcontroller" sender:self];
```

pass identifier as you have set for `UIViewController` segue.

Comment: Segment control is added on view and i am able to load view controller from 1-->2-->3 but unable toad it back like  3-->2-->1 or 3-->1 like and also did swapping code in container view control from the given link i did code --   http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers       Can u please suggest me how can i use segment control insted of swipe button in that.